# problem in read entry from directory handle

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in php and I'm learning this programming language.

[My directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKD22.png)

When I run this code :

```html
$pathname = dirname(__FILE__);
$handle = opendir($pathname);

while (($item = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    echo "<br/>".$item;
}

closedir($handle);
```

my output is :

```html
.
..
app2.php
app3.php
app1.php
ali.txt
amin.txt
amin
Tamrin2.php
```

But when I run this code :

```html
    $pathname = dirname(__FILE__);
$handle = opendir($pathname);

while ((readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    echo "<br/>".readdir($handle);
}

closedir($handle);
```

My output is :

```html
..
app3.php
ali.txt
amin
```

What is the difference between these two codes‌ ?!

Comment: The `readdir()` call in the while condition for the second example throws its result in the garbage, so you're only getting every second result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to [`readdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) reads the next entry from the directory, so in...

```
while ((readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    echo "<br/>".readdir($handle);
}
```

it is called once to control the `while()` loop and then once to output the entry.  So you will see every other entry.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
while ((readdir($handle) !== false)
```

this calls `readdir()`, compares the result to `false`, and uses this to determine whether to continue the loop. When you then do

```
echo "<br/>".readdir($handle);
```

it reads the *next* filename and echoes it.

So you echo every other filename in the directory.